# Android RecyclerView (CardView) как установить ширину между карточками

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Здравствуйте. После обновления библиотек android support до версии 23.3.0 увеличилась ширина между карточками (cardview) как это исправить.

[image: Скриншот эмулятора]

Comment: Кстати, похоже, что мы с вами для одного сайта читалку пилим) Вот мой репозиторий на gitHub: [тык](https://github.com/mohaxspb/TProger)

Comment: да это так, делаем для одного сайта

Comment: Я только недавно начал, опыта пока маловато у меня. Студент.

Comment: Ну, я студентом такого вообще не умел, так что у вас большая фора)

Comment: Если на гитХаб выкладывали код - я б посмотрел)

Comment: нет не выкладывал

Comment: я поменял на layout_height на wrap_content так и осталось

Comment: Ну, покажите целиком разметку элемента... Вообще должно помочь, если корневому контейнеру разметки элемента так высоту проставить

Comment: <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_post"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

Comment: Добавляйте код в вопрос через его правку. И я не о разметке с RecyclerView говорю, а о разметке элемента списка, отображаемого в нём)

Comment: Все я понял. где ошибся. Теперь все нормально. Спасибо. На этом сайте я только сегодня зарегистрировался и пока еще не разобрался.

Comment: Если один из ответов решил вашу задачу, то вы можете отметить его верным, нажав на галочку слева от тела вопроса)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо просто поменять в разметке элементов `RecyclerView` высоту с `match_parent` на `wrap_content`